# what is the path of the config file in UCM

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I'm trying to follow a blogpost for UCM workflows, and the post mentioning adding 2 config entries to the config file , can any one tell what is the exact path to change those config variables

```
 AutoContributorAdvancesOnUnlock=true
 AutoContributorAllowsReview=true
```

url

```
http://webmonkeymagic.blogspot.com/2011/05/avoiding-workflow-contribution-step.html
```

i've tried to add them to file called config.cfg in the following path, restarted the server but it didn't work

```
/user_projects/domains/wcc_domain/ucm/cs/config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to do this:
Log in to UCM and look at *Administration -> Admin Server -> General Configuration*. Add your values under *Additional Configuration Variables*

If you still want to find the file, do like this:
Log in to UCM and look at *Administration -> Configuration for ... -> Instance directory*. In that folder you will find config/config.cfg. If you find the values you added (as above) here, you are on the right track.

Comment: Make sure to not have any spaces before or after the "=" and Make Sure to spell it right with proper capitalization.You will need to bounce the server to see the changes.